# apply robust scaling to a column in mysql

Tags: mysql, scikit-learn, statistics, feature-selection

Robust scaling is a useful statistical technique to remove outliers from data. it simply subtracts the median from data and scale it according to the quantile range.

you can read more about it in this URL: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.RobustScaler.html

My questions are: Are there any built-in function in MySQL to perform this scaling task for a specific column? And if not how can I do it in a simple and efficient way?

I would appreciate any help

Comment: when you google 'robust scaling' + MySQL, and your own question appears top of the list, I think that tells you all you need to know about MySQL's built in capabilities in this regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I can say this does not exist in MySQL and most of Row-based RDBMS.  Nevertheless, this can be implemented using multiple views, but this will not be efficient enough.

To solve such a problem, I would suggest using materialized views, nested views and columnar DBMSs